# How to exit a while-loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(void) {
   char ch;
   while (1) {   
      if ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) 
      {
         break;
      }
      putchar(ch);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

How do I escape from this `while`? I had tried with EOF but it didn't work.

Comment: `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`. `ch` should be an `int`. This is actually fairly important.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, and if you assign its return value to a `char`, you may a) convert `EOF` to a value that is not converted back to `EOF` for the comparison or b) convert valid `char`s to `EOF` for the comparison. `ch` should be an `int`.

Answer (score 7):

I think you mean:

```
int ch;
```

Because `EOF` won't fit in a `char`.

Also:

```
if ((ch=getchar()) == EOF)
       break;
```

Your logic is backwards.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
char ch;
```

is wrong, `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`. The type of `getchar()`'s return value is `int` so this code should be:

```
int ch;
```

Also, as pointed out, your logic is backwards. It loop while `ch` is not `EOF`, so you can just put it in the `while`:

```
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please answer to this one?.When while condition will be false?

Answer (score 2):

check with the while. It's more simple

```
while((ch=getchar())!= EOF) {
     putchar(ch);
}
```

The EOF is used to indicate the end of a file. If you are reading character from stdin, You can stop this while loop by entering:

- `EOF` = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (for Linux)
- `EOF` = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows)

  You can make your check also with `Escape` chracter or `\n` charcter

Example

```
while((ch=getchar()) != 0x1b) { // 0x1b is the ascii of ESC
     putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Yes it's easy but how to get out of while.What I need to enter to get false in while condition.

Comment: Sorry to say still I am not getting false condition in while

Comment: when you want to finish input characters, Just enter Escape character and then Enter

Comment: and if you change the check by `(ch=getchar()) != '\n'`, Just enter newline character (ENTER) and the while will break

Comment: @PoornaDurgaYeddu If you use `(ch=getchar())!= EOF` you can stop this wile loop by entering `CTRL+D` For Linux and `CTRL+Z` for Windows