# Create a program to solve for powers without using pow() and while using a While loop: PROBLEM WITH "UNDEFINED" ANSWRES

Tags: c, linux

My assignment for my CS class is to create a program in C to solve for a power without utilizing the pow() command and while utilizing the While loop. 
My program works, however, I am having a problem with my "undefined" answers and I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double base, exponent, result, result2, result3;

    printf("enter  two numbers to fit this format x^n\n");
    printf("x can be any number. insert n only as a whole number.\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", & base, &exponent);

    if ((base == 0) && (exponent == 0)) {
        printf("UNDEFINED\n");
    } else if ((base == 0) && (exponent <= -1)) {
        printf("UNDEFINED\n");
    }

    result = 1;
    result2 = 1;

    while (exponent != 0) {

        if (exponent <= -1) {
            result2 = result2 * base;
            exponent = exponent + 1;
        } else if (exponent > -1) {
            result = result * base;
            exponent = exponent - 1;
        }
    }

    result3 = 1 / result2;

    if ((result3 < 1) && (result > 0)) {
        printf("The answer is %lf\n", result3);
    } else {
        printf("the answer is %lf\n", result);
    }
}
```

When I enter my base and exponent that should give me an "UNDEFINED" answer (power and exponent are both 0 OR when the base is 0 and the exponent is a negative number), my answer comes up as "undefined" but the program also tells me the solution is "1". How do I get the "answer is 1" thing to go away?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I “break” out of an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8523538/608639), [How to exit a while-loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13803072/608639) and [How to end a program with an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21789720/608639). Also see [How to debug a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590931/608639).

Comment: Also, remove the `>` and make it nicely indented to make it easier to read.

Comment: Hey @larn i have edit your question, kindly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the condition like this:

```
if ((base == 0) && (exponent <= 0)) {
    printf("UNDEFINED\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a error code to the return to indicate a unsuccesful execution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop your program when you have an "undefined" case. 
Then you can just add "return (0);" after your printf.

I advise you to have a better indentation syntax, yours is rather illisible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) // better to add "void" when you're not using program's argument
{

    double base;
    double exponent;
    double result;
    double result2;
    double result3;

    printf("enter  two numbers to fit this format x^n\n");  
    printf("x can be any number. insert n only as a whole number.\n");   
    scanf("%lf %lf", &base, &exponent);

    if (base == 0 && exponent <= 0) { // useless surparenthesis that make harder to read the line
        printf("UNDEFINED\n");
        return (0);
    }
    // You can merge your two condition "if ((base==0) && (exponent==0))" and " if ((base==0) && (exponent<=-1))" into one

    result = 1;
    result2 = 1;

    while (exponent != 0) {
        if (exponent <=- 1) {
            result2  = result2 * base;
            exponent = exponent + 1;
        } else { // useless if ... if (exponent > -1)
            result = result * base;
            exponent = exponent - 1;
        }
    }

    result3 = 1 / result2;

    if (result3 < 1 && result > 0) {
        printf("The answer is %lf\n", result3);
    } else {
        printf("the answer is %lf\n", result);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the code after the else if is excuted because your program doesnt terminate after the printf. To avoid that you can either add a return after the printf or you put the rest of the code in a else like that:

OPTION 1:

```
...
    if ((base == 0) && (exponent == 0)) {
            printf("UNDEFINED\n");
            return 0;
    } else if ((base == 0) && (exponent <= -1)) {
            printf("UNDEFINED\n");
            return 0;
    }
...
```

OPTION 2:

```
int main() {

  double base, exponent, result, result2, result3;
  printf("enter  two numbers to fit this format x^n\n");
  printf("x can be any number. insert n only as a whole number.\n");
  scanf("%lf %lf", & base, & exponent);

  if ((base == 0) && (exponent == 0)) {
    printf("UNDEFINED\n");
  } else if ((base == 0) && (exponent <= -1)) {
    printf("UNDEFINED\n");
  } else {

    result = 1;
    result2 = 1;

    while (exponent != 0) {

      if (exponent <= -1) {
        result2 = result2 * base;
        exponent = exponent + 1;
      } else if (exponent > -1) {
        result = result * base;
        exponent = exponent - 1;
      }

    }

    result3 = 1 / result2;

    if ((result3 < 1) && (result > 0)) {
      printf("The answer is %lf\n",
        result3);
    } else {
      printf("the answer is %lf\n", result);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody tells you to add a `return` statement after printing `UNDEFINED`. That is the answer to your question, however, you must also test the return value of `scanf`.

As it is now, if `scanf` is unable to read the two values, the values remain *undetermined* because they have not been initialized. (They are automatic variables, allocated on the stack, and automatic variables are never initialized.)

So:

```
    while (scanf(....)!=2) printf("You must enter two numbers. Please try again\n");
```